# English translation of "Une inégalité pour martingales à indices multiples et ses applications"

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, martingales, translation

Does anyone know of a English translation of "Une inégalité pour martingales à indices multiples
et ses applications" by Renzo Cairoli. Or could translate the statement of the martingale convergence theoerm and his definition of multiindex martingale.

Link; http://archive.numdam.org/article/SPS_1970__4__1_0.pdf

References where theorem is stated clearly also works!

Comment: I found the notes [French for Mathematicians: A linguistic approach](http://people.brandeis.edu/~jbellaic/French.pdf) by Joël Bellaïche very helpful. He argues that someone who knows English can learn how to read a mathematical text in French without too much effort.

Comment: @gsa thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand\Om\Omega$ $\newcommand\F{\mathcal F}$ $\newcommand\M{\mathcal M}$
With the help from Google Translate:

> Throughout the work $m$ is a fixed integer $\ge2$ and $j$ runs through the
> integers from $1$ to $m$. For each $j$, $(\Om_j,\F_j,P_j)$ is a probability space. Set $\Om=\prod\limits_j\Om_j$, $\F=\bigotimes\limits_j\F_j$, $P=\bigotimes\limits_j P_j$. The expectation with respect to $P$ will be denoted by $E$.

> The processes that we are going to consider are (unless otherwise stated)
> real, defined on $(\Om,\F,P)$ and admitting as a set of indices
> a set of points with $m$ coordinates of which each coordinate traverses
> a countable subset of $\mathbb R$. This set will be endowed with the relation $(r_1,\dots,r_m)\le(r'_1,\dots,r'_m)$ if $r_1\le r'_1,\dots,r_m\le r'_m$.

> We will denote by $\M$ the class of martingales
> $$(X_{r_1,\dots,r_m}, \F_{r_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes\F_{r_m})$$
> relative to an increasing family of product [$\sigma$-]fields contained in $\F$.

Apparently, here the general definition of a martingale over a directed partially ordered index set is assumed; see e.g. Section [Filtrations and martingales](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/%7Eporbanz/teaching/G6106S15/Chapter1_27Jan15.pdf).

> **Theorem 2**. If for the martingale $(X_{n_1,\dots,n_m})\in\M$ we have
> $$\sup_{n_1,\dots,n_m}E\{|X_{n_1,\dots,n_m}|(\log^+|X_{n_1,\dots,n_m}|)^{m-1}\}<\infty$$
> (therefore, in particular, if $\sup\limits_{n_1,\dots,n_m}E|X_{n_1,\dots,n_m}|^p<\infty$ for some $p> 1$), then the limit
> $$\lim_{n_1\to\infty,\dots,n_m\to\infty}X_{n_1,\dots,n_m}$$
> exists (and is finite) a.s.

Comment: The notes contained what I wanted, isnt theorem 1.8 more general?

Comment: @user1 : I don't understand your comment. What notes? What theorem 1.8? Where?

Comment: http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~porbanz/teaching/G6106S15/Chapter1_27Jan15.pdf page 6

Comment: @user1 : Yes, Theorem 1.8 in the notes linked to in my answer is more general than Theorem 2 translated in my answer, in two ways: (i) the index set in Theorem 1.8 can be any directed set and (ii) the integrability condition in Theorem 2 is of course narrower than the general uniform integrability condition in Theorem 1.8 in the notes linked to in my answer.